# Cannot find module that is defined in tsconfig `paths`

Tags: typescript, alias, tsc, tsconfig, ts-node

I am trying to setup aliases for my mock server. Whenever I try to compile `ts` files, it returns error that it couldn't find proper modules even though those are defined in `tsconfig,json`->`paths`

Folder structure:

```sh
├── server
│   └── src
│       └──/json
├── src
│   └──/modules
├── tsconfig.json
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es2015.promise"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "paths": {
            "@project/app/modules/*": [
                "modules/*"
            ],
            "@project/server/data/*": [
                "../server/src/json/*"
            ]
        },
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "tools"
    ]
}
```

Error:
`Error: Cannot find module '@project/server/data/accounts/accountsList'`

Comment: does it work for @project/app/modules/*?

Comment: Nope, none of the aliases can be resolved

Comment: my config, has include flag which points to ['src']. try it.

Comment: do you happen to use it with webpack?

Comment: I just want to use typescript, I think it's not necessary to configure webpack for it

Comment: I had to check because if you had webpack, you would need to declare you aliases there too

Comment: I have webpack configured for my application, but my mock server was not using it.

Comment: well, the situation is quite confusing and unclear. I suggest reading this article https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html, there is nothing I can help you more with

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using, `tsconfig-paths` package.

Comment: @JamilAlisgenderov what was the specific command you used for cdk + tsconfig-paths?

Answer (score 68):

well, after suffering a few hours, I got a solution,
I am using the `ts-node` package, and I got the same error `Error: Cannot find module '@modules/logger'`

You need to add `ts-node` configuration in the `tsconfig.json` file.
You can get more infor at [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#paths-and-baseurl)

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file look like

```
{
    "ts-node": {
        // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
    },
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7"],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "build",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,

        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
            "*": ["node_modules/*"]
        },

    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

and here is my `package.json`

```
"_moduleAliases": {
        "@modules": "build/modules",
        "@core": "build/core"
    }
```

You need to install this package as a dependency of module alias `npm i module-alias`

And don't forget to add  `import 'module-alias/register';`
in your entry file of the application as module alias dependency.

Comment: this is the finest solution, tsconfig is a different beast than the resolution of node itself, so you need a thing to allow node recognize your shiny aliased paths, as it is shared in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514947/1778979

Comment: Adding the `tsconfig-paths` dev dependency and `tsconfig-paths/register` allowed the path "aliases" to work under `ts_node` execution.  No need for `module-alias` if that is all that is desired.

Comment: For this to work you will need to import the module-alias dependency in you entry file `import 'module-alias/register';` as stated in this article https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353.

Comment: Nailed it man, thank you very much! With `ts-node` indeed it works differently

Comment: Following integration process of _module-alias_ from https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353 worked for me

Comment: My man (sorry for assuming your gender), your solution works best. Stay blessed. 

Comment: thanks, I needed the     "include": ["src/**/*"]

Comment: Holly Molly... didn't think that ts-node would be the issue here. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I just can't thank you enough. Worked like a charm

Comment: I finally gave in and got module-alias and it worked as shown. Though to stress to others who come by you may not need the ts-node bit if that's not already in your setup (I'm not using it and it still builds/runs fine).

Answer (score 21):

After battling it for some time I figured it out you need to `include` all directories using `tsconfig-paths` in your main `tsconfig.json`. Working version of your `tsconfig.json` file could be

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
...
        "paths": {
            "@project/app/modules/*": [
                "src/modules/*"
            ],
            "@project/server/data/*": [
                "server/src/json/*"
            ]
        },
    },

    "include": [
        "./src",
        "./server"
    ],
}
```

Comment: But this way it'll include all folders in src even without the paths. in my project I had the same name for a folder in src like a library I included. And it was complaining as it tried to read the local folder when imported, not the package.

Comment: it worked for me with dev mode, but not with tsc build and then running `node dist/index.js` so I added "dist/*" to paths along with "src/*" and key is "@/*" and now it works.

Comment: One thing to note is that the @ symbol is a convention to indicate the root of the project.

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same issue. I tried many things and now i got a solution which works for me. I have an app and a library in my angular project. I want to use a library alias in my app.

I have following structure:

```
├── projects
│   └── lib
│       └── src
│           └── lib
│               └── lib-service.ts
│           └── index.ts
│   └── app
│       └──tsconfig.app.json
├── tsconfig.json
```

In the ***tsconfig.json*** file in the root folder I have following paths defined:

```
"paths": {
  "my-lib": [
    "projects/lib/src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

There I access an ***index.ts*** file where I define the things I want to export. In my case the index.ts file has the following entry:

```
export * from './lib/lib-service';
```

Now I can access the ***LibService*** in components of the app with the help of the alias:

```
import {LibService} from 'my-lib';
```

It is important to mention that this soloution don't work if I add this entry to the ***tsconfig.app.json*** file. I think the IDE (in my case WebStorm) searches for aliases in the ***tsconfig.json*** file which is close to the root folder. So I extend the ***tsconfig.json*** in my ***tsconfig.app.json***

```
"extends": "../../tsconfig",
```

Maybe you have to restart you IDE to remove the red underline of the import line.

I hope this solution works for you. You have to to a little bit more of setup work because you have to define the classes you want to export in the index.ts file. But in case of using libraries it make sense because you don't want to make everything visible for other app.

Comment: app works like a cham! But typescript still complaining even after restarting the IDE as Error: Can't find module.

Comment: I had to restart VS Code to get rid of the red underline!

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach Random thing, you can usually get rid of the red lines by restarting the TS server within VS code. `cmd+shift+p` type `Restart TS Server`

Comment: This should be in bold: 
Maybe you have to restart you IDE to remove the red underline of the import line.

Answer (score 17):

My issue was that my `tsconfig.app.json` which extended my `tsconfig.json` was overriding the `"baseUrl"` option incorrectly. I removed it from the `tsconfig.app.json` so it did not have a `"baseUrl"` or `"paths"`. In the end, my `tsconfig.json` had the following compiler options:

```
"baseUrl": "src/",
"paths": {
    "@shared/*": ["shared/*"],
    "@client/*": ["client/*"],
    "@server/*": ["server/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The following `tsconfig.json` worked for me, allowing `import { foo } from '@models'` etc for the associated `index.ts` barrel exports:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@environment": ["./src/environments/environment.ts"],
      "@models": ["./src/app/shared/models/index.ts"],
      "@services": ["./src/app/shared/services/index.ts"]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 8):

TypeScript `path` properties can reliably resolve typings-based URLs such as an interface.

`The intended behaviour is to allow TypeScript to resolve type information`[[1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866#issuecomment-246789510)]

Most us seem to be experiencing that a path pointing to an actual dependency wont always compile as we expect. This is apparently by design despite [what the doc says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "jquery": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Read this great breakdown by Mitchell Simoens - [Why TypeScript Paths Failed Me](https://mitchellsimoens.com/2019/08/07/why-typescript-paths-failed-me/)

Found this after setting up @paths to my shared folders throughout the app.
During compilation TS paths where breaking and actual builds were missing all sorts of modules. On a personal note this is a huge disappointment that TS can't reliably resolve dependencies this way.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR;

`npm i -D module-alias`

and add the mappings from your `tsconfig.json` paths to `_moduleAliases` in your `package.json`

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "foo": "dist"
}
```

As for the reasoning behind it, using `"jsx": "react"` in conjunction with `"module": "commonjs"` prevents you from being able to use absolute imports even though `baseUrl` and `paths` are configured correctly. A detailed discussion can be found in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866).

Answer (score 4):

When u use the bare variant with just `tsconfig.json` (`"typescript": "^4.4.4"`) without any third party libraries:

1. Add `baseUrl`.

```
"baseUrl": ".",
```

2. Add `paths`.

```
"paths": {
      "@app/assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@app/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@app/features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "@app/hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@app/navigation/*": ["src/navigation/*"],
      "@app/services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@app/utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
}
```

3. Add `package.json` with a `name` of alias for each path inside the destination folder.

```
// src/assets/package.json
{
  "name": "@app/assets"
}
```

Comment: this name is not allowed in package.json because of @ char

Answer (score 4):

If your having this issue with **Jest** then you can edit your `jest.config` to include a [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) that would looks something like this:

```json
{

  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@project/server(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/server/$1"
  }
}
```

So this uses a regex to map the import `@project/server...` to the path `"<rootDir>/server/$1"`

Answer (score 2):

I put it both in [webpack resolve alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) and the tsconfig paths and it worked that way :)

> ```js
> module.exports = {   //...   resolve: {
>     alias: {
>       Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
>       Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/'),
>     },   }, };
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily define simple path resolver like this:

`loader.js`

```
const Module = require("module");
const originalResolveFilename = Module._resolveFilename;
const tsConfig = require("./tsconfig.json");
const Path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
if (!tsConfig.compilerOptions || !tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl)
    throw "Compiler options Base URL (compilerOptions.baseUrl) is required in tsconfig.json.";
const basePath = Path.resolve(tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl, tsConfig.compilerOptions.outDir);

//Inspired by https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths but that one does not work with VS Code
Module._resolveFilename = function (request) {
    if (tsConfig.compilerOptions && tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths[request] instanceof Array) { //Supports only without wildchars, but enough for our use
        const pathsTried = [];
        for (const reqPath of tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths[request]) {
            const modPath = Path.resolve(basePath, reqPath) + ".js";
            if (fs.existsSync(modPath)) return modPath;
            pathsTried.push(reqPath);
        }
        throw "Module " + request + " not found, paths tried: " + pathsTried.join(", ");
    }
    const ret = originalResolveFilename.apply(this, arguments);
    return ret;
};
```

and than reference it from VS Code's `launch.json` like this:

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Node.js",
  "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "./loader.js"],
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/run.ts",
  "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
  "outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
  ]
}]
```

It does not support patterns in `paths` but with this stub it can be added.

`tsconfig.json` should look like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "out", //required
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./", //required
    "paths": {
        "InjectableStub": [ //requires 2
            "myapp/myfolder/mymodule", //used in runtime
            "./myfolder/mymodule //used in compile-time
        ]
    }
}
```

at least for me `tsc` creates sub-folder in name of the root folder in `out` that's why the 2 registrations.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this in your tsconfig.json

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

Comment: it works, but why? :D any pointers to e.g. documentation, please?

Comment: moduleResolution docs are here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: that's in my tsconfig.json but it does not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Please do not include your base folder when defining the path. In the following case, your path should start from 'app'.

**folder structure**

```
├── src
│   └──/app
├── tsconfig.json
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@app/navigation/*": ["app/navigation/*"]
}
```

Comment: An explanation as to why would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're instead using `ts-node-dev` with a custom local `tsconfig.json`, make sure to call your script by setting the `TS_NODE_PROJECT` environment variable, not by passing the `--project` command line argument to `ts-node`.

`tsconfig-paths` only reads the environment variable.

So you want to call your script like this :

```js
TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"folder/tsconfig.json\" ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --project \"folder/tsconfig.json\" ./folder/main.ts
```

Altogether you want to:

1. Install `tsconfig-paths`

```
npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths
```

2. Add your *baseUrl* and *paths* to your (local) `tsconfig.json`
3. Run the `ts-node` command with the `TS_NODE_PROJECT` environment variable set, and `"-r tsconfig-paths/register"` .

No "_moduleAliases", "import 'tsconfig-paths/register'" or ' "ts-node": {"require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]}' needed.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I wanted to run a typescript script using `ts-node` / `ts-node-esm`. None of the solutions worked in my project (Next.js), but then I found [tsx](https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx). I can now run my script like this:

```bash
npx tsx script.ts
```

[tsx](https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx) automatically resolves the `paths` from `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile the `"baseUrl"` may work, my solution was to add the same exact paths to my `babel.config.js` (as I am working with React Native/Expo).
So my config now looks something like this:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      "module:react-native-dotenv",
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['./'],
          alias: {
            "@services": "./services",
            "@components": "./components",
            "@screens": "./screens",
            "@styles": "./styles",
            "@models": "./models",
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

After this, just stop the Expo and rebuild it.

Answer (score -1):

Check *angular.json* file if its "build" -> "options" config has "tsConfig" option set as your changed tsconfig file.

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "src/assets/styles"
        ]
      },
............
```

The above one is my angular.json file, and I configured it to use *tsconfig.app.json*.
In this case, "paths" should be added in *tsconfig.app.json* file.

Answer (score -1):

just add  "moduleResolution" : "Node",  on tsConfig